# Using Tesla P100 as Compute Device

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

We are using a cloud service which provides a NVIDIA Tesla P100.

Apparently Blender does not show the GPU as a compute device:

[image: Cycles devices]
[image]

I am using Blender 2.82. Maybe there is some experimental version that supports such a graphics card? Am i on the wrong track about that? What do you say?

Here is some system information:

[image]

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 IDE [Natoma/Triton II]
00:01.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 USB [Natoma/Triton II] (rev 01)
00:01.3 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Cirrus Logic GD 5446
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio network device
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Red Hat, Inc. QEMU PCI-PCI bridge
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Red Hat, Inc. QEMU PCI-PCI bridge
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Red Hat, Inc. QEMU PCI-PCI bridge
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Red Hat, Inc. QEMU PCI-PCI bridge
00:08.0 PCI bridge: Red Hat, Inc. QEMU PCI-PCI bridge
00:09.0 PCI bridge: Red Hat, Inc. QEMU PCI-PCI bridge
00:0a.0 PCI bridge: Red Hat, Inc. QEMU PCI-PCI bridge
00:0b.0 PCI bridge: Red Hat, Inc. QEMU PCI-PCI bridge
00:0c.0 Communication controller: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio console
00:0d.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP100GL [Tesla P100 PCIe 16GB] (rev a1)
00:0e.0 Unclassified device [00ff]: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio memory balloon
02:01.0 SCSI storage controller: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio block device
05:01.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. ES3000 V3 NVMe PCIe SSD (rev 45)
```

Comment: Use the prorpietary Nvidia drivers, not the open source.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Blender 2.79b rendering on the same GPU but in Google Colab, I force using GPU with a Python script.

I had some difficulties but I found that Google put some restriction on the GPU. I just had to remove `libtcmalloc-minimal4` package and reinstall it from Ubuntu repositories and now every thing is okay. Something like

```
    sudo apt-get remove libtcmalloc-minimal4
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install libtcmalloc-minimal4
```